# Where is the implementation of javax.validation.Valid aka @Valid

Tags: java

I know this one can valid `{ METHOD, FIELD, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER }`, I want to know how did it work, by checking  `== null` or  `!= null`? where is the implementation of that, sorry I have such few experience in this field, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is an annotation and annotations do not have implementations. Also `@Valid` does not enable any particular validations - just enables the validation on the target.

However if you are interested in particular checks implementations of `javax.validation` have a look in one of reference implementation: https://hibernate.org/validator/

Comment: This is only true in the narrowest technical sense. Validation annotations express _constraints_ that certainly do have implementations.

Comment: I think I wrote that in the first sentence ;)

Comment: Hmm, I mean if we have `@NotNull` before `private String manufacturer;`, there must be `if (null == manufacturer) { ...; }` somewhere right? where does this `CHECKING` code?